# Lambda authorizer (node 18.x runtime) ending before execution of aws-sdk command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-sdk-js

I have a Lambda authorizer (used by API Gateway) running on a NodeJS 18.x runtime
In this Lambda, I need to use some Command from @aws-sdk. My code is running correctly until the Command. The Lambda exit without issue and without finish the execution.

The last console.log displayed in my CloudWatch is console.log(command), and then nothing else. All my client.send(input) are never executed.

```
var region = process.env.USER_POOL_REGION; //e.g. us-east-1
import {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    ListUsersCommand,
    AdminListGroupsForUserCommand
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: region });

export const handler = async function (event, context) {
    ValidateToken(pems, event, context);
}

async function getUsers() {
    console.log("getUsers function");

    let usersList = [];
    let userAttributes = [];
    let batchResponseListUsers = {};

    let input = {
        UserPoolId: userPoolId
    }
    
    try {
        do {
            input.PaginationToken = batchResponseListUsers.PaginationToken;
            console.log(input);
            const command = new ListUsersCommand(input);
            console.log(command);
            const responseListOfUsers = await client.send(command);
            console.log(responseListOfUsers);

            for (const attribut of responseListOfUsers['Users']) {
                userAttributes.push(attribut['Attributes']);
            }
            for (const user of responseListOfUsers['Users']) {
                usersList.push(user['Username']);
            }
            batchResponseListUsers = responseListOfUsers;
        } while (batchResponseListUsers.PaginationToken);

        return usersList;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function ValidateToken(pems, event, context) {
    console.log("ValidateToken function");

    var token = event.authorizationToken.replace("Bearer ", "");
    var decodedJwt = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
    var username = decodedJwt.payload["cognito:username"];

    var usersList = await getUsers();
    console.log(userList);

    context.succeed(buildPolicy); //buildPolicy not displayed in this example
}
```

```
INFO { UserPoolId: 'eu-west-1_xxxxxxxxx', PaginationToken: undefined }
INFO ListUsersCommand {
    middlewareStack: {
      add: [Function: add],
      addRelativeTo: [Function: addRelativeTo],
      clone: [Function: clone],
      use: [Function: use],
      remove: [Function: remove],
      removeByTag: [Function: removeByTag],
      concat: [Function: concat],
      applyToStack: [Function: cloneTo],
      identify: [Function: identify],
      resolve: [Function: resolve]
    },
    input: { UserPoolId: 'eu-west-1_xxxxxxxxx', PaginationToken: undefined }
}
END RequestId: 19c6dbfd-8e55-4e90-af49-2dbca1c4e369
REPORT RequestId: 19c6dbfd-8e55-4e90-af49-2dbca1c4e369  Duration: 991.60 ms Billed Duration: 992 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 117 MB Init Duration: 883.66 ms
```

My package.json is

```
{
    "name": "function-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
      "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.388.0",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "jwk-to-pem": "^1.2.5",
      "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "jest": "^27.5.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).